# can we install the different SSL certificate on different Nginx-location in same nginx-server for same host name and same port?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I got the situation where I have to configure different certificate for two different application on the nginx server. Both application request will be proxy from the nginx server to there respective running application .. 
I have to configure this for same server name and same port.

Any suggestion will be appreciated here.

Thanks

Comment: Please describe your problem with the example urls that what exactly you want to do with nginx proxy

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with stock NGINX, because [`ssl_certificateq`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) cannot be set per-location.

You can achieve what you want by using Lua nginx module, using, in particular [`ssl_certificate_by_lua_block`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block), writing logic for loading different SSL cert depending on current URI.